# Set every ComboBox entry in a different color

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colors, combobox

As you can see in the title, I would like to display my entrys in a way like [this ComboBox](http://www.office-loesung.de/files/imagecombo.jpg). But in my case it is enough to use white and grey.
The object which will be added should look like this:

```
var item:Object = {label:"Dummy1", data:1 , "ValidItem":true};
if(item.ValidItem){setThisEnryInaDifferentColor();}
```

It should work like this pseudo code.

I´m using Flash with ActionScript 3 (no Flex, no AIR)

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the backgroundColor property of the textfields within your selected item.

Comment: I cant edit now the Color of the selected Item, if the box is closed, but I need to change the Color of all Items in the ComboBox if the List is open